# Matlab : How to plot the constellation diagram for this method?

Tags: matlab, constellation-diagram

I am trying to generate symbols +1,-1 using a function by partitioning the interval of the function into two levels. The function is the [Tent Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map). This in a way achieves bpsk modulation.  I want to see the constellation diagram for bpsk . But I am getting error

```
Undefined variable "comm" or class "comm.RaisedCosineTransmitFilter".

Error in GenerateData (line 32)
txfilter = comm.RaisedCosineTransmitFilter('Shape','Normal', ...
```

So, I typed in >>

```
help comm.RaisedCosineTransmitFilter
```

and I believe that my Matlab does not have this class because this is the output of the help

`comm.RaisedCosineTransmitFilter not found`.

How can I view the constellation diagram?

This is the way I generate +1/-1 symbols for bpsk.

```
%generate bpsk
 N = 10000; %number of data points
x(1) = rand(1,1);
for i =2:N  
x(i) = 2 * min(x(i-1), 1 - x(i-1)); %Tent map implementation
end
   modData = 2*(x>0.5)-1;  %generating symbols
  % modData holds the modulated symbols
  qpsk = comm.QPSKModulator;
  Rup = 16;
txfilter = comm.RaisedCosineTransmitFilter('Shape','Normal', ...
    'RolloffFactor',0.5, ...
    'FilterSpanInSymbols',10, ...
    'OutputSamplesPerSymbol',Rup);
  constDiagram = comm.ConstellationDiagram('SamplesPerSymbol',Rup, ...
    'SymbolsToDisplaySource','Property','SymbolsToDisplay',100);

txSig = txfilter( modData);
constDiagram(txSig)
```

Could somebody please show the correct way to obtain the constellation diagram. I am using Matlab2011b version on 64 bit i7 processor. Thank you.

Comment: So, if your symbols are +1 and -1, why not just do `plot([-1 1],[0 0],'x')`?

Comment: Note the `'x'` in my plot command. You really need to read the entire docs for `plot`. In general, you can do something like `plot(real(C),imag(C),'x')` where `C` is a complex array holding your constellation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are using is from the Communication Systems Design Toolbox. You might have it not installed/licensed on your PC.

In case you just want to plot a constellation diagram, you can go with this code (Note, that it works for QAM constellations, not BPSK (since BPSK has only one domain)).

```
values = -7:2:7;  % Values in real and complex domain
[X, Y] = meshgrid(values, values);
QAM = X(:) + 1j*Y(:);
plot(QAM, 'x')
```

Actually, the QAM constellation contains all combinations of possible real and complex values. Hence, you need the cartesian product between real and complex parts. Taking [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834254/cartesian-product-in-matlab), you can plot the constellation diagram.

[image]

Comment: Well, your code above creates the same constellation diagram. Then, what's the problem?